# Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, visual-studio-code

I can't find my mistake, but I understand that it has something to do with the versions in build.gradle not matching.

Any help is appreciated.

Error log:

> Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

My build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2" //17
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2" //19
    implementation "com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    //implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please add this to your app gradle dependencies

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

and don't forget to enable it :

```
  defaultConfig {
    ......
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```